# Casting the shadow of a inner object on the outer of a sphere

Tags: shadowcatcher

I'm using eevee as render engine, the sphere is a shadow catcher ([video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gzAr3VyLMOY)), I don't know how to see the shadow on the front face of the sphere. [file](https://www.mediafire.com/file/kjzsiyum3wzmsyg/cube.blend/file)

[image]

Thank you !

Comment: Couple questions, What is the intended purpose of this effect? You could theoretically use a cast modifier to simulate the "shadow" being cast by just manipulating the geo of the cube itself. And do you absolutely have to use EEVEE or is Cycles an option? You can't bake in EEVEE but if you were to bake out this effect and then use that as a texture for both sides of the mesh material then you could make it work, and still render in EEVEE.

Comment: @Jakemoyo The purpose is to be able to project on the sphere multiple polyhedron, so I wish to find a method working for multiple cases, where I don't need to always edit the inner object.
I can use cycles, I just better approached my project with eevee. In cycles, with the shadow catcher on, I didn't have anything on the outer sphere (it was working on the inner sphere).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your use case, I think you could do this more easily by using this stack of modifiers, It's all totally procedural and can work with any object. Once you apply custom materials to the geometry it will essentially be indistinguishable from the intended effect.

This is only from my understanding of your project, given your comment. If you absolutely have to have it done with a light and the shadow it casts then it seems far more difficult.

*Modifiers:*
[image: Modifiers]

*Before:*
[image: Objects before deformation]

*After:*
[image: Objects after deformation]

You can even animate the factor amount on the cast modifier to animate the deformation.

[image]

Comment: Nice idea, I didn't think I could put the wireframe modifier before the subdivision and the cast. At first glance, it seems to be what I need (on regular polyhedron it acts as the same way as a projection on the sphere, I need to check on strange cases).

Comment: I also found a way with a light and a reflexive shader on the sphere but it's not as clean and simple as your solution. Thank you.
https://i.imgur.com/klk82e8.mp4